# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDiv' of undefined

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

Good daytime.

I need to insert a map component in WebView app.  Code is completely same as example from official doc.

```
  loadMap() {
    let self=this;
    this.showLoading('Loading map').then(()=>{

      console.log('Setting env vars...');

    Environment.setEnv({
        'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_RELEASE': _here_was_key_,
        'API_KEY_FOR_BROWSER_DEBUG': _here_was_same_key_
    });

    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
         target: {
           lat: 59.939095,
           lng: 30.315868
         },
         zoom: 18,
         tilt: 30
       }
    }; // presence of this doesn't matter

    console.log('Creating map...');

    // Create a map after the view is ready and the native platform is ready.
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas',mapOptions); // last param doesn't matter
    console.log('Map created.',this.map);

    // Wait the maps plugin is ready until the MAP_READY event
    /* // all code below (markers, their handlers, camera) is commented during debug
    */
    self.loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'display':(howToChoosePickPoint=='map')?'block':'none'}">
  <ras-map></ras-map>
</div>
```

"ras-map" tag contains component code:

```
<div id="map_canvas">
        <button ion-button small (click)="zoomOut()">-</button><button ion-button small (click)="zoomIn()">+</button>
</div>
```

Buttons location inside or outside the main div tag doesn't matter.

It worked just before framework update, but for now after a couple of seconds after GoogleMap object creation (line "Map created. GoogleMap {_objectInstance: Map}" in console log) I see an error message in console: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDiv' of undefined
    at CordovaGoogleMaps._remove ...". Map (and any of HTML elements belong Google) does not appear at all.

Comment: what is `map_canvas_osa` in your code?

Comment: The same maps should be in three different places in project (but on different pages). So I gave them unique names and forgot to change the code back after copy-pasting. Now it's fixed, but the problem still exists.